# Get the trigger that invoked the lambda when it is invoked

Tags: aws-lambda

I have an AWS lambda with multiple triggers.  When the lambda is invoked, I'd like to be able to determine which trigger invoked the lambda within the lambda code itself.  Is this information available somehow?  I tried looking at the event object and the context object, but I did not see that information available.  Is there some api I can call to get the trigger or another way to get that information reliably?

Comment: `eventSource` is in the payload. Do you have multiple sources that are the same?

Comment: @Leon The sources are all different lambda triggers.  How is the `eventSource` object passed in to my lambda?  My lambda entry point looks like this `handler = (event, context, callback)` {'

Comment: can you not send that info as part of event itself while setting up the trigger?

Comment: `event` structure lambda receive is different depending on the event source. However, I am sure that the `event` contains all information you want.

Answer (score 0):

Answering late but may help someone else looking for solution-
As @Leon mentioned, ***eventSource*** would work. For example, below are two different payload for s3 and sqs-

```
    {
  "Records": [
    {
      "eventVersion": "2.1",
      "eventSource": "aws:s3",
      "awsRegion": "us-east-2",
      "eventTime": "2019-09-03T19:37:27.192Z",
      "eventName": "ObjectCreated:Put",
      "userIdentity": {
        "principalId": "AWS:AIDAINPONIXQXHT3IKHL2"
      },
      "requestParameters": {
        "sourceIPAddress": "205.255.255.255"
      },
      "responseElements": {
        "x-amz-request-id": "D82B88E5F771F645",
        "x-amz-id-2": "vlR7PnpV2Ce81l0PRw6jlUpck7Jo5ZsQjryTjKlc5aLWGVHPZLj5NeC6qMa0emYBDXOo6QBU0Wo="
      },
      "s3": {
        "s3SchemaVersion": "1.0",
        "configurationId": "828aa6fc-f7b5-4305-8584-487c791949c1",
        "bucket": {
          "name": "DOC-EXAMPLE-BUCKET",
          "ownerIdentity": {
            "principalId": "A3I5XTEXAMAI3E"
          },
          "arn": "arn:aws:s3:::lambda-artifacts-deafc19498e3f2df"
        },
        "object": {
          "key": "b21b84d653bb07b05b1e6b33684dc11b",
          "size": 1305107,
          "eTag": "b21b84d653bb07b05b1e6b33684dc11b",
          "sequencer": "0C0F6F405D6ED209E1"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
 }
```

SQS-

```
    {
    "Records": [
        {
            "messageId": "11d6ee51-4cc7-4302-9e22-7cd8afdaadf5",
            "receiptHandle": "AQEBBX8nesZEXmkhsmZeyIE8iQAMig7qw...",
            "body": "Test message.",
            "attributes": {
                "ApproximateReceiveCount": "1",
                "SentTimestamp": "1573251510774",
                "SequenceNumber": "18849496460467696128",
                "MessageGroupId": "1",
                "SenderId": "AIDAIO23YVJENQZJOL4VO",
                "MessageDeduplicationId": "1",
                "ApproximateFirstReceiveTimestamp": "1573251510774"
            },
            "messageAttributes": {},
            "md5OfBody": "e4e68fb7bd0e697a0ae8f1bb342846b3",
            "eventSource": "aws:sqs",
            "eventSourceARN": "arn:aws:sqs:us-east-2:123456789012:fifo.fifo",
            "awsRegion": "us-east-2"
        }
    ]
}
```

Now you can use -

```
source = event['Records'][0]['eventSource']
```

This should give the resource name, in case of s3 you would get ***aws:s3***, and for sqs- ***aws:sqs***.